# Inserting characters into existing sequence of strings in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a structure like this:

```
<faults>
  <fault componentName="comp1">
    <introduceWhen>Time1</introduceWhen>
    <signals>
      <signal name="sig11" value="1"/>
      <signal name="sig22" value="1"/>
    </signals>
  </fault>
  <fault componentName="comp2">
    <introduceWhen>Time2</introduceWhen>
    <signals>
      <signal name="sig44" value="0"/>
    </signals>
  </fault>
</faults>
```

I would like to gather up the values of all the signals under each fault and put them into a title attribute so that I can show detailed info about a fault when hovering over that specific table cell. I have managed to get the info I need into a sequence of strings, like so:

```
<td title="comp1 sig11 1 sig22 1 comp2 sig44 0">comp1 1 1 Time1 comp2 0 Time2</td>
```

Using this:

```
<xsl:template match="faults">
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="fault/@componentName | 
                          fault/signals/signal/@name | 
                          fault/signals/signal/@value"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="fault/introduceWhen | fault/@componentName |
                        fault/signals/signal/@value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But what I would like to have is this (the `&#xA;` are newlines):

```
<td title="comp1&#xA;sig11: 1&#xA;sig22: 1&#xA;comp2&#xA;sig44: 0">comp1 1 1 Time1 comp2 0 Time2</td>
```

I tried using `replace($faultDetails, ' (\d) ', ': $1&#xA;')` but found out that `$faultDetails` actually is a sequence of strings without spaces, whereas replace only operates on a contiguous string. As I write this I realize that I can get almost there with this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fault/@componentName | fault/signals/signal/@name | 
                      fault/signals/signal/@value" separator="&#xA;"/>
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single expression to create the attribute value then you can use

```
<xsl:template match="faults">
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="title" select="fault/(@componentName/string(), signals/signal/concat(@name, ': ', @value))" separator="&#xA;"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

That creates `<td title="comp1&#xA;sig11: 1&#xA;sig22: 1&#xA;comp2&#xA;sig44: 0"/>` for me with Saxon 9.6.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know you could use comma in that way, very nice solution!

Comment: Oh wait, it's the fact that you make them into strings that makes it all work, no?

Comment: If you simply wanted a sequence of nodes all with the same separator you could do it with e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="title" select="fault/(@componentName, signals/signal/(@name, @value))" separator="&#xA;"/>`. However, as you want to have the signal name and value separated by a colon which I have done with e.g. `signals/signal/concat(@name, ': ', @value)` the other item in the sequence needs to be converted to a string explicitly. And I unintentionally did that in the wrong place too, I will edit the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to enumerate explicitly what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="/faults">
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="title">
            <xsl:for-each select="fault">
                <xsl:value-of select="@componentName"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="signals/signal">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name, @value" separator=": "/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- ??? -->
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This was the solution I ended up using actually, since Firefox 38.2 - which I'm stuck using - couldn't handle the more brief version. Thanks!

Comment: @Fylke You have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0 - but no browser supports XSLT 2.0. This solution will not work in XSLT 1.0 either: the `xsl:value-of` instruction will only return the value of the first node in the selected node-set.

Comment: _No_ browsers support XSLT 2.0?! Wow okay, that's good to know. But this solution does work, so I assume you are referring to the other answer? I suppose I might as well relabel the file as XSLT 1.0 then.

Comment: "*But this solution does work*" No, I don't think so.You should get an error, or an incomplete result.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right of course. I changed the select statement from `"@name, @value"` to `"@name, ': ', @value"` and ditched the separator, then it works fine.